# Update Geojson file using Geolocation [Onclick]

Tags: javascript, json, geolocation, leaflet, geojson

I have a local .json file with lat/long coordinates for each feature, and a column **Distance** that is empty (randomly putting 999).

The overall goal is to display markers in a leaflet map and filter it based on geolcoation using a button.

I am trying to create one button that is able to:

1. Get my current location
2. Calculate distance for each feature in my json file (for loop)
3. **[Blocking point]** Update the column Distance / or create a new column
4. filter json file based on distance (for ex. show me markers where distance is under 100 km)

I got inspiration from this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/zross/47760925fcb1643b4225)
but had suffered with the "callback hell" issue.
I am right now in the 3rd step : I managed to calculate distance. but not working outside the function.

Here the code I'm using, The blockage is in the For loop: the distance column is not being updated

```
var allmarkers = L.markerClusterGroup();
var markersdist100 = L.markerClusterGroup();

// Load json file
var promise = $.getJSON("./data/FILE.geojson");
promise.then(function(data) {
    // Update distance in json data
    // Geolocation part to get current position
    var userPositionPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data1) {
                resolve(data1);
            }, function(error) {
                reject(error);
            });
        } else {
            reject({
                error: 'browser doesn\'t support geolocation'
            });
        };
    });
    userPositionPromise.then(function(dataa) {
        lat = dataa.coords.latitude;
        lng = dataa.coords.longitude;
        console.log(lng); // check ok : lng of current location
        console.log(data.features.length); //check ok : json length for iteration
        // For loop to calculate the new distance
        for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
            data.features[i].properties.distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat, lng, data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0], data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1]);
            console.log(data.features[i].properties.distance); //check ok : showing the right distance
        }
    })
    console.log(data.features[0].properties.distance); //check BUG : showing initial distance [999]

    //all data
    var all = L.geoJson(data, {
        pointToLayer: style_markers,
    });

    // data filtered by distance, see the function [filter_distance]
    var distance100 = L.geoJson(data, {
        pointToLayer: style_markers,
        filter: filter_distance
    });

    // Filter distance on button click
    $("#distance100").click(function() {
        markersdist100.addLayer(distance100);
        allmarkers.addLayer(all);

        map.addLayer(markersdist100);
        map.removeLayer(allmarkers);
    });

});

// FUNCTIONS

function filter_distance(feature, other) {
    return feature.properties.distance < 100;
};

function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
    var a =
        Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    return d;
};

function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
};
```

Do you have any recommendations on how to structure my code to access the data with the updated Distance column

Thank you

Comment: `console.log(data.features[0].properties.distance);` is called before `data.features[i].properties.distance = ...`.

Comment: Nice point ! I found a solution thanks to your remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution !

I had only to put the **var distance100** right after the For loop

With these functions : **On button click, you are able to filter markers in a Leaflet map based on your current location (by updating distance in your json file)**

Many cases are tackled here : read/access and update a Geojson local file, filter Leaflet markers onclick, use geolocation coordinates in another function, calculate distance ...

the updated code is below (loading the map and the controls is not covered):

```
var allmarkers = L.markerClusterGroup(); //markercluster plugin using leaflet
var markersdist100 = L.markerClusterGroup();

// Load json file
var promise = $.getJSON("./data/FILE.geojson");
promise.then(function(data) {
    // Update distance in json data
    // Geolocation part to get current position
    var userPositionPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data1) {
                resolve(data1);
            }, function(error) {
                reject(error);
            });
        } else {
            reject({
                error: 'browser doesn\'t support geolocation'
            });
        };
    });
    userPositionPromise.then(function(dataa) {
        lat = dataa.coords.latitude;
        lng = dataa.coords.longitude;
        console.log(lng); // check ok : lng of current location
        console.log(data.features.length); //check ok : json length for iteration
        // For loop to calculate the new distance
        for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
            data.features[i].properties.distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat, lng, data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0], data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1]);
            console.log(data.features[i].properties.distance); //check ok : showing the right distance
        };

        // data filtered by distance, see the function [filter_distance]
        var distance100 = L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: style_markers,
            filter: filter_distance
        });

        // Filter distance on button click
        $("#distance100").click(function() {
            markersdist100.addLayer(distance100);
            allmarkers.addLayer(all);

            map.addLayer(markersdist100);
            map.removeLayer(allmarkers);
        });

    });

    //all data
    var all = L.geoJson(data, {
        pointToLayer: style_markers,
    });

});

// FUNCTIONS

function filter_distance(feature, other) {
    return feature.properties.distance < 100;
};

function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
    var a =
        Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    return d;
};

function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
};
```

A screenshot of my map

[image]

Hope this can help others in their use cases

Feel free to optimize the code and share it with us